# How to stop a driver from running in Windows PE

Tags: drivers, windows-10, avg-antivirus, windows-pe

My computer has unfortunately succumb to an error caused by AVG Anti-virus and upon boot of my computer it tells me that certain `.sys` files are either corrupted or missing.

Upon searching the directory it told me they're in (`\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\avgboota.sys`) which I saw nothing.

I was wondering how I could stop this driver from running by editing the Windows 10 configuration through Windows PE?

Comment: Are you sure that driver is loading, because normally WinPE wouldn't load that type of driver, it has no need for it.

Comment: WinPE isn't loading the driver. Windows 10 is. I want to know a way of disabling it through Windows PE.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just delete the file, provided you can mount the system drive, but you don't have to use WinPE to do that.

Comment: I do because I cant boot into Windows at all nor can I do it through safe mode since it wont let me or give me any start up options since that error prevents me from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into safe mode and uninstall/update AVG.

Windows PE isn't required for this task.

Comment: I cant boot into Safemode through Windows 10. Thanks for your help though.